# Confused about free variables

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

What is the difference between a free variable and a basic variable (the opposite of a free variable) when the free variable only appears once in only one equation in the system. It seems to me that the purpose of getting row reduced echelon form is to only get one equation for each basic variable (correct me if I'm wrong), but what happens when a free variable also only appears once? Why can't the free variable be considered a basic variable?

Comment: Your terminology is rather opaque, it would help if you explained a bit more. "Free variable" is a standard term but "basic variable" is not. Also, I would hate to guess what RREF means.

Comment: Just made a correction. For basic variable, I meant the opposite of a free variable --- a variable that can't be simply anything but something well defined by other variables.

Comment: The opposite of a free variable is presumably a [bound variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables)

Comment: [Free vs. basic variable](https://www.math.wsu.edu/math/faculty/hudelson/free.html). A basic variable is one with a basic column in the RREF, that is a column with a pivot. *Basic* comes from the fact pivot columns form a standard basis. This answers your question "*Why can't the free variable be considered a basic variable?*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that what you refer to as a 'basic variable' is more commonly referred to as a bound variable, which you might find useful in learning more about linear algebra. In a sense which variables are free and which are bound is just a question of choice. Consider the somewhat degenerate example of the equation
$$
x_1+2x_2 = 0
$$
Which has the corresponding matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We could think of this as $x_1$ being a bound variable and $x_2$ being free and that would be correct, but we would be equally correct (if a bit more confusing) to write our original equation $2x_2+x_1 = 0$, which has RREF
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&\frac{1}{2}&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The general idea that you can take from this is that as long as one is careful you can permute the columns of your matrix (or equivalently change the order of your variables) and still faithfully encode a linear system.

Comment: Why can’t you have two bounded variables?

Comment: @mathisfun you totally can, that just isn't the case in the example I gave. In the given example, only one of $x_1,x_2$ can be bound, since the bound variable by definition depends on the other one. It can be helpful to write the final expression in terms of your bound variables, i.e. $x_1 = -2x_2$ in the first presentation I gave or $x_2 = -1/2x_1$ in the second. In either case, we call the variable(s) on the right as being free, but once they are fixed to a particular value, the variable on the right is bound because it is completely determined by the expression on the right. Does that help?